# Improving Code Efficiency in Dataset Generation

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, for-loop

I am trying to generate a dataset where each day in a given year range has a fixed number of stores. In turn, each store sells a fixed number of products. The products specific to each store and day have a value for sales (£) and number of products sold.

However, running these for loops takes a while to create the dataset.

Is there anyway I can improve the efficiency of my code?

```
# Generate one row Dataframes (for concatenation) for each product, in each store, on each date

dataframes = []
for d in datelist:
    for s in store_IDs:
        for p in product_IDs:
            products_sold = random.randint(1,101)
            sales = random.randint(100,1001)
            data_dict = {'Date': [d], 'Store ID': [s], 'Product ID': [p], 'Sales': [sales], 'Number of Products Sold': [products_sold]}
            dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data_dict) 
            dataframes.append(dataframe)

test_dataframe = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

Comment: Did you look at my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason your code is really slow now is that you have the dataframe construction buried inside of your triple loop.  This is not necessary.  Right now, you are creating a new dataframe inside of each loop.  It is much more efficient to create all of the data in some type of format that `pandas` can ingest and then create the dataframe *once*.

For the structure that you have, the easiest mod you could do is to make a list of the data rows, append a new dictionary to that list for each row as you are constructing now, and then make a df from the list of dictionaries...  Pandas knows how to do that.  I also removed the list brackets of the items you had in your dictionary.  That isn't necessary.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

datelist = [1, 2, 4, 55]
store_IDs = ['6A', '27B', '12C']
product_IDs = ['soap', 'gum']


data = []  # I just renamed this for clarity
for d in datelist:
    for s in store_IDs:
        for p in product_IDs:
            products_sold = random.randint(1,101)
            sales = random.randint(100,1001)
            data_dict = {'Date': d, 'Store ID': s, 'Product ID': p, 'Sales': sales, 'Number of Products Sold': products_sold}
            data.append(data_dict)  # this is building a list of dictionaries...

print(data[:3])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())
```

Yields:

```
[{'Date': 1, 'Store ID': '6A', 'Product ID': 'soap', 'Sales': 310, 'Number of Products Sold': 35}, {'Date': 1, 'Store ID': '6A', 'Product ID': 'gum', 'Sales': 149, 'Number of Products Sold': 34}, {'Date': 1, 'Store ID': '27B', 'Product ID': 'soap', 'Sales': 332, 'Number of Products Sold': 60}]

   Date Store ID Product ID  Sales  Number of Products Sold
0     1       6A       soap    310                       35
1     1       6A        gum    149                       34
2     1      27B       soap    332                       60
3     1      27B        gum    698                       21
4     1      12C       soap    658                       51
[Finished in 0.6s]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Jeff H! I've made the adjustment you recommended. However, it still seems to be taking an uncharacteristically long time to generate. I think one of the main issues might be that the data I have to generate is for a time period of over three years (for each day). I don't suppose it's possible to use a map function of sorts that might aid in improving efficiency?

Comment: so, let's get a sense of the size....  when complete, what is the size of the dataframe you construct.  This should be the product of the sizes of the 3 lists, which you can confirm with `df.info()`.  I can add to the post on how you can collapse your loops down into list comprehensions, but I'm curious what performance you have now, because that likely won't be a night & day change.  And what is current execution time?

Comment: Size is approximately 3 and a half years (in days) = 1277 multiplied by 99 stores = 126,423 multiplied by 8999 products = 1,137,680,577 rows. Currently, the loops haven't yet finished iterating...

Comment: Yeah, that's really too big to be practical.  I'd suggest you back up and figure out what your purpose is here.  If you are trying to model or simulate something this simple, you do not need this much data, especially because you are drawing from uniform distributions.  All of the summary statistics can be determined analytically without any data.  If you are modeling something and want this type of info, you could generate it "on the fly" when needed.  If you really want to create something this huge, then a database is a great next step.

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize your sizes are huge?

> Size is approximately 3 and a half years (in days) = 1277 multiplied
>   by 99 stores = 126,423 multiplied by 8999 products = 1,137,680,577
>   rows.

If you need in average 16 bytes (which is already not much) you need at least 17GB of memory for this!

For this reason, `Store_IDs` and  `Product_IDs` should really be just small integers, like index in a table of more descriptive names.

The way to gain efficiency is to reduce function calls! E.g. you can use `numpy` random number generation to generate random values in bulk.

Assuming all numbers involved can fit in 16bits, here's one solution to your problem (still needing a lot of memory):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def gen_data(datelist, store_IDs, product_IDs):
    date16 = np.arange(len(datelist), dtype=np.int16)
    store16 = np.arange(len(store_IDs), dtype=np.int16)
    product16 = np.arange(len(product_IDs), dtype=np.int16)
    A = np.array(np.meshgrid(date16, store16, product16), dtype=np.int16).reshape(3,-1)
    length = A.shape[1]
    sales = np.random.randint(100, 1001, size=(1,length), dtype=np.int16)
    sold = np.random.randint(1, 101, size=(1,length), dtype=np.int16)
    data = np.concatenate((A,sales,sold), axis=0)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data.T, columns=['Date index', 'Store ID index', 'Product ID index', 'Sales', 'Number of Products Sold'], dtype=np.int16)
    return df
```

FWIW on my machine I obtain:

```
            Date  Store ID  Product ID  Sales  Number of Products Sold
0              0         0           0    127                       85
1              0         0           1    292                       37
2              0         0           2    180                       36
3              0         0           3    558                       88
4              0         0           4    519                       79
...          ...       ...         ...    ...                      ...
1137680572  1276        98        8994    932                       78
1137680573  1276        98        8995    401                       47
1137680574  1276        98        8996    840                       77
1137680575  1276        98        8997    717                       91
1137680576  1276        98        8998    632                       24

[1137680577 rows x 5 columns]

real    1m16.325s
user    0m22.086s
sys 0m25.800s
```

(I don't have enough memory and use swap)